# how to set a condition for GROUP_CONCAT with search value

Tags: mysql, group-by, group-concat

I have a MySQL table
Booktable

```
+--------+-------------+-----+  
| bookno | bookname    | ... |  
+--------+-------------+-----+  
| 1      | Stack       | ... |  
+--------+-------------+-----+  
| 2      | OverFlow    | ... |  
+--------+-------------+-----+
```

Genretable

```
+--------+-------------+-----+  
| bookno | Genrename   | ... |  
+--------+-------------+-----+  
| 1      | Fantasy     | ... |  
+--------+-------------+-----+  
| 1      | Adventure   | ... |  
+--------+-------------+-----+  
| 2      | Horror      | ... |  
+--------+-------------+-----+
```

Translatortable

```
+--------+-----------------+-----+  
| bookno | translatorname  | ... |  
+--------+-----------------+-----+  
| 1      | Harry           | ... |  
+--------+-----------------+-----+  
| 1      | Potter          | ... |  
+--------+-----------------+-----+  
| 2      | Jame            | ... |  
+--------+-----------------+-----+
```

I want to query and show result like

```
+---------+----------------------+---------------+ 
| bookname| Genrename            |translatorname |           
+---------+----------------------+---------------+
| Stack   |Fantasy , Adventure   |Harry,Potter|  
+---------+----------------------+---------------+  
| OverFlow| Horror               |Jame           |  
+---------+----------------------+---------------+
```

I already try with group_concat and group by but the result is like

```
+---------+--------------------------+-----------------+
| bookname|Genrename                 |translatorname   |         
+---------+--------------------------+-----------------+
| Stack   |Fantasy , Adventure,Horror|Harry,Potter,jame|
+---------+-----------------+---------------------------+
| OverFlow|Fantasy , Adventure,Horror|Harry,Potter,jame|      
+---------+-----------------+---------------------------+
```

thankyou very much

Comment: From the given sample how `Stack`  has authorname  `Steve,job` as shown in the result ? Could you explain a bit on that logic of 2  `Authorname` columns ?

Comment: For example each book can have up to 10 author, 10 genre and 10 translator. so I want to query and show the book name with all author name or genre name in the same row. but what I got it all genre name or author name which don't care about book name or book no (it should be relate to bookno(FK))

Comment: Well the query should be simple in that case all you need to select the data something like `b.bookname, group_concat(b.authorname) as authors, group_concat(g.Genrename) as Genrename, group_concat(t.translatorname) as translatorname from Booktable b join Translatortable t on t.bookno = b.bookno join Genretable g on g.bookno = b.bookno group by b.bookname`

Comment: I try this with select `b.bookname,group_concat(a.authorname) as authorname,group_concat(g.Genrename) as Genrename, 
group_concat(t.translatorname) 
as translatorname from Booktable b left outer join Translatortable t on t.bookno = b.bookno
left outer join Genretable g on g.bookno = b.bookno left outer join authortable a
on a.bookno = b.bookno   group by b.bookname;`

but I get double record on authorname, and translatorname but it work with genrename.


Edited* I fix it with distinct thankyou very much

Comment: Yes `group_concat()` accepts distinct something as `select group_concat( distinct some_col) as some_col`, infact you  can also use order by in group_concat to display the author or genre names in alphabetical order.